# Magento2 How to get customer group from sales order item collection

Tags: magento2, sales-order-item

I want to get customer group from sales order item collection.
How do i get that?

In Magento 1 it is like this

> $customer_group =
>   Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($order->getCustomerGroupId());

how can i get it in magento 2.

I have item collection and i want customer group for each item.

How to get please answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join two collections or tables to get customer group

I had joined two tables order table and order item table

refer the following solution to join two collections

[Join two colections](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/276140/how-to-join-sales-order-collection-and-order-item-collection)

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch customer group using below code.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository        
) {
    $this->groupRepository = $groupRepository;
}

public function getCustomerGroup()
{  
   $customerGroup = $this->groupRepository->getById($order->getCustomerGroupId());
   echo $customerGroup->getCode(); // 
}
```

I hope it'll work, let me know if you need further assistance. Happy Coding :)